# Erro com CSS no JQuery FullCalendar ao usar Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Estou trabalhando com a biblioteca JQuery `FullCalendar` e tenho uma função que pinta certas linhas do calendário de acordo com uma condição.

A função funciona perfeitamente no Internet Explorer, mas no Goolge Chrome as linhas não são pintadas.

Já tentei trocar `.css('background-color', '#FFFFFF;')` por `.style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF;"`, mas nada acontece.

Qual a melhor maneira de mudar a cor de fundo de um elemento para ser corretamente exibido no Google Chrome? Abaixo segue o código. Os símbolos `'>'`, `'<'`, `'&&'`, etc. foram substituídos pelas entidades HTML correspondentes pois esta função está em um arquivo `.XHTML` do JSF.

```
if(timeSlot &gt;= str &amp;&amp; timeSlot &lt; obj.horaTermino)      
//Change 13 and 18 according to what you need
{


  $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF;');
    //$(this).closest('tr').style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF;";


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obtive uma resposta no StackOverFlow em inglês que solucionou o problema. simplesmente precisei retirar o ponto e vírgula final, ficando assim o código:

```
$(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
```

Segue o link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463873/jquery-fullcalendar-css-error-with-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF!important;');
```

Veja se no Inspect Element do Chrome ele está adicionando o fundo branco no objeto.

O **!important** prioriza a propriedade em que está sendo atribuído caso tenha a mesma no mesmo elemento.